# JavaScript form attribute null error

Tags: javascript

I have a java script code which will set some values in a form

```
function editCategory(categoryId)   {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/product/fetchEditCategory",
    data: "categoryId=" + categoryId,
    success: function(response){
        var productManagerForm = document.getElementById('productManager');
        productManagerForm.ceName.value = response.catName;........
```

My JSP is -

```
    <form id="productManager" name="productManager" action="/product/" method="post">
    <div id="editCategory">
        <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Category Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" id="ceName" /></td>              
            </tr>   
</div>      
<td><a href="#editCategory" id="cat"  onclick="editCategory('p1')">edit</a></td>
```

I am getting following error on running this code -

```
Message: 'ceName' is null or not an object
```

Can someone please tell me what is the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ceName cannot be accessed as a property of productManagerForm.

Try this:

```
var ceName = document.getElementById('ceName');
ceName.value = response.catName;........
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to try this:

```
var productManagerForm = document.getElementById('productManager');
var ceName = productManagerForm.getElementById('ceName');
ceName.value = response.catName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to acheive with this function, but

```
 var productManagerForm = document.getElementById('productManager');
```

returns a node Element.  ceName is a child of this element.  Not an attribute of this element.  You can get the element directly by using :

```
var ceName = document.getElementById("ceName");
```

or by going down the node tree until you find this... considering ceName is the ID, it is much faster to get to it directly using the getElementById().

Hope this helps!